# Create columns in R within a for loop

Tags: r, for-loop

I have a data frame in R and I would like to create new columns within a for loop. I have tried many things for the last 2 days but without success.  At the end, I did find a solution that seems to work, but it doesn't seem very straight forward.  I was wondering if anybody has a more elegant way to do this.
Sorry if this has already been addressed but I couldn't find similar question on SO
Here is my example.

```
x <- runif(20)
a <- as.data.frame(x)
for (i in 1:100){
  d <- x + i
  a <- cbind(a, d)
}

c <- 1
for (i in 1:100){
  c[i] <- paste0("colum", i)
    }
colnames(a) <- c("x", c)
```

Thanks in advance for any good suggestions to make this process all within one loop instead of 2.

Comment: For one thing, you can remove the second for loop completely.  `paste0("colum", 1:100)` gives the same result.

Comment: Oh yes. thanks for that.  I'm slightly editing the questions then.

Answer (score 2):

Why not:

```
a[2:11] <- sapply(1:10, "+", a[[1]])
```

The names would be:

```
names(a) <- c("x", paste0("column", 1:10))
```

Answer (score 1):

In this case you can avoid both loops. In R you should always try to use vectorised statements when possible. In this case you can do this using addition fairly easily, one way is

```
result <- matrix(x + rep(0:100, length(x)), ncol = 101, byrow = TRUE)
result <- as.data.frame(result)
names(result) <- c("x", paste0("column", 1:100))
```

You can also keep the matrix structure if you only want to store numbers. Also, you should avoid using `cbind`, `rbind` and other functions that increase the size of an object with each iteration in loops. The R inferno is a good book to read.

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps what you are looking for is `eval` and `parse`, as such:

```
for (i in 1:100) {
    eval(parse(text = paste0('a$colum', i, ' <- whatever_you_want_your_column_to_contain'))
}
```

This will create named columns and their contents in a single statement.

Comment: how can I take care of assigning only single rows in that context? For instance, when I create the different columns and their names in each loop I would like to assign different numbers to the certain rows of each column.

Comment: You are using eval(parse()) as a work around for the non-standard evaluation of $. That is just bad advice. Instead you should use [[. I suggest reading help("$") which mentions this as the recommended approach for passing element names programmatically.