# Create new columns in data table with for loop

Tags: r, for-loop, data.table

Is there a simple way to create columns within a for loop? I know this question has been asked here multiple times and I have tried this solution adjusted to my case

```
for (i in 1:100) {
  eval(parse(text = paste0('a$colum', i, ' <- whatever_you_want_your_column_to_contain')))
}
```

from one of the posts, but it did not help. I have an existing data table data and I am trying to create columns P_1 to P_30 within a for loop and then assign them NULL (I am just trying to pre-define the columns). I have tried this:

```
for (i in 1:30) {
  eval(parse(text = paste0('data$P_', i, ' <- NULL')))
}
```

but without any success. Can you please suggest any approach that would work?

A related question - how to refer to those columns in another loop, if I have again column P_i where i is from 1 to 30, how to refer to data$P_i within a loop?

**Edit:**

I have this data table to make an example:

```
customer_id <- c("1","1","1","2","2","2","2","3","3","3")
account_id <- as.character(c(11,11,11,55,55,55,55,38,38,38))
obs_date <- c(as.Date("2017-01-01","%Y-%m-%d"), as.Date("2017-02-01","%Y-%m-%d"), as.Date("2017-03-01","%Y-%m-%d"),
              as.Date("2017-12-01","%Y-%m-%d"), as.Date("2018-01-01","%Y-%m-%d"), as.Date("2018-02-01","%Y-%m-%d"),
              as.Date("2018-03-01","%Y-%m-%d"), as.Date("2018-04-01","%Y-%m-%d"), as.Date("2018-05-01","%Y-%m-%d"),
              as.Date("2018-06-01","%Y-%m-%d"))
variable <- c(87,90,100,120,130,150,12,13,15,14)    
data <- data.table(customer_id,account_id,obs_date,variable)
```

and I found out that the problem is really in assigning that NULL to those columns, because when I am doing this based on the post's advice:

```
for (i in 1:30) {
   eval(parse(text = paste0('data$P_', i, ' <- 1')))
}
```

it really works, just with the NULL instead of 1 it does not. So, it is not a bad advice, it just does not work with NULL.

Comment: When asking for help, you should include a simple [reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) with sample input and desired output that can be used to test and verify possible solutions. Data.frames really don't like NULL columns, they should be zero length vectors anyway.

Comment: Are you really dealing with a data.table? It rather seems like you have "just" a data.frame. Also, you really should study help("[[").

Comment: Please provide a link to the post you are referring to. I have a strong urge to downvote it and let others know that it contains bad advice.

Comment: Recommending eval/parse and a loop work with with data is not good advice. If you want to fill with 1, you can just do `data.frame(Map(function(x) 1, paste0("P_", 1:30)))`

Comment: @Roland Here's the answer making that recommendation, somehow well received so far: https://stackoverflow.com/a/29400819

Comment: OK, so you have a data.table. You should read help("set").

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's a `data.table` answer - I think you were close, you just didn't have the right syntax to append a column to a data table:

```
for (i in 1:30) {
  data[, paste0("P_", i) := "whatever_you_want_your_column_to_contain"]
}
```